# Compare 2 CSV Files data of more than 2 columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 2 CSV files. Each file has the same column names as mentioned in below script.

I am trying to compare `New.csv` with `Old.csv`. To compare, I look for every `Alertname` in `Old.csv`, find the matching alert in `New.csv`, and then check the time of alert from the `Timeraised` column. If the alert is present and the alert time is more than 3 hours different, then do not show the data. But if its less than 3 hours then show the alert and create `Output.csv`.

**Example** -

[OLD.csv File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsSPs.png)

```
AlertName,AlertDescription,PrincipalName,Severity,TimeRaised
Memory Alert,Event Description: Memory issues found on xyz server,ABC,Error,13-04-2020 06:47
Disk Space Alert,Event Description: Disk space issues found on xyz1 server,ABS,Error,13-04-2020 06:31
```

OLD.csv includes alert as below:

```
Alertname: Memory Alert
TimeRaised: 03-04-2020 06:23
```

New.csv includes alert as below:

```
Alertname: Memory Alert
TimeRaised: 03-04-2020 9:24
```

I don't want that alert to show in `Output.csv` as time difference is more than 3 hours. If it is less than 3 hours, include it in `Output.csv`.

**My Work**- I am only able to compare Alerts on both file on basis of Alertname only, its not able to compare 2 different variable at time, means I can't compare Alertname & Timeraised at once from below code due to restriction. Can anyone guide me through this.

```
$path= "C:\CSV"
$Old = import-csv $path\Old.csv    # Original file
$New = import-csv $path\New.csv  # New ALert File



$Results =Compare-Object $Old $New -property AlertName -passThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } 

$Array = @()       
Foreach($R in $Results)
{
    If( $R.sideindicator -eq "=>" )
    {
        $Object = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{

            AlertName = $R.AlertName
            AlertDescription = $R.AlertDescription
            PrincipalName = $R.PrincipalName
            Severity = $R.Severity
            TimeRaised = $R.TimeRaised


        }
        $Array += $Object
    }
}

#Display results in console
$Array | Export-Csv $path\output1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The csv examples you post don't look like Comma Separated Values at all. Please post **valid** examples, so people that want to help do not have to guess.

Comment: Could you open your CSV file in notepad and send us some **redacted** rows?  What you sent wasn't a normal CSV

Comment: CSV attached for reference.

Comment: So now you show us the csv as link to an image... Please edit the question again and add the first few lines of the csv files as formatted **text**

Comment: Done, if this is ok.

Comment: It would be nice if you get whatever system creates these files to put the TiimeRaised values into standard ISO-8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Make sure to add the property `timeraised`

```
// previous code 
$Results =Compare-Object $Old $New -property "AlertName","timeraised" -passThru |             
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } 
// rest of code
```

Comment: But I have to compare Timeraised value difference , How can i achieve that above simply not working.

Comment: Can you show me your result this is my result`````` AlertName AlertDescription PrincipalName Severity TimeRaised
memory Alert   abc 03-04-2020 9:24

Comment: My point is we can't compare 2 properties at the same time, even if we do then it will compare the same value but I don't want to compare Timeraised with same value, I need to check if timeraised value difference is more than 3 hr or not.

Comment: can you upload old and new csv i wil test on correct data to compare

Comment: I have added image but file I am not able to see any option. Thanks

Comment: Any one get chance to look at it?